# How to sample audio at Nyquist frequency with MSP430F5438?

Tags: audio, adc, dac, sampling

I want to:

1. Input an analog audio track
2. Using the microcontroller ADC, convert it to a digital output
3. Then have the microcontollers/boards timer sample the data at selected intervals
4. Resample the "Sampled audio track" at twice the highest frequency content
5. Convert it back to analog as a perfect reconstruction of the initial audio track

Using Fourier Analysis I will determine the highest frequency at which I will sample the track at.

It sounds easy enough and straight forward, but what I need is to program this in C and utilize my MSP430 chip/experimenters board to sample the track.
I'm going to be using Texas Instruments CCS and Octave for my programming and debugging. I am using the [MSP430F5438 Experimenter Board](http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/msp-exp430f5438.html).

**Is C the right language for this? Can I get any examples of how to sample the track at Nyquist frequency using C? What code in C will tell the board to utilize the ADC component?** And any recommended information that is similar or that will help me on this project.

Comment: A really cool way to do this is to make a rough PSD meter with an audio crossover, setting sampling frequency to the minimum frequency bin achieving a threshold. This is heavy hardware design, but that is what makes it cool! Note that it would still be inferior to oversampling.

Comment: Interesting thought of how to go about this. Ill look into it and see if its more work then just oversampling the data.

Comment: @Martin, it is definitely more work! ;)

Comment: How much work do you think a ADC, oversampling process, then DAC in c would take?

Comment: ADC and DAC can be hardware peripherals, leaving the micro to do nothing but wait for ADC interrupts to read values from the ADC registers or timer interrupts to write values to the DAC registers -- it's the FFT that can leave it breathless. It is worth learning where to optimize a FFT algorithm (including looking for alternatives) for cycles and memory while staying within your requirements.

Comment: How about this thought, only use the board for the ADC and DAC (since i already have the example code) and then doing the dsp process using my computer, This would work right?

Comment: You would have to transmit and receive the data to and from your computer with a serial port or using an external USB chip (FTDI, etc.), which isn't a problem near 50 kHz, but seems overly complicated. If you can use a PC, why not get it to do it all, and just plug into the audio input and line out jacks?

Comment: @Martin, If one answer has helped you come to a decision more than others, perhaps you could consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do your entire project in a desktop PC.  In fact, if I had to do it, I would start with the desktop:

1. a .wav file is already sampled at a high frequency, often 44100 or 48000 Hz.
2. determining the highest frequency can be done with an FFT.  For prototyping, I would link [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/).
3. downsampling to an arbitrary frequency is a bit hard, because downsampling involves low-pass filtering.  You need to set up a filter for each frequency.  Look at [libsamplerate](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/) and see how it sets up a SINC function to convolve against.
4. Converting back to the original sample rate will involve another low-pass filter.  See again libsamplerate.

I believe I would implement this in several passes, for ease of debugging:

1. Get everything working in Matlab or Octave first.  Octave has libraries to do all the filtering and Fourier analysis.
2. Get everything working in C on PC, linking FFTW and libsamplerate for the downsampling / upsampling.
3. Rewrite the C code with explicit-width variable types (e.g., int16_t instead of "short") and replace FFTW and libsamplerate with own code so that it compiles standalone.
4. In C for the MSP430 or whatever DSP you've got, write interrupt routines to sample data on the ADC and output it on the DAC.  Test that this works, just going from input to output.
5. Take the working code from step 3 and compile it for the MSP430 or whatever.  Then wedge it in to the working code from step 4 to operate on the sampled data between ADC and DAC.

This may seem like a lot of steps, but it is much more likely to make a working result than heroically coding everything up in one huge MSP430 application, then trying to debug it on the dev board.

Comment: How would i then use nyquist or oversample it? ADC isnt so much of a problem because they give example code, but chouldnt i just patch the sampling code into the already given ADC code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "use nyquist."  Please explain.

Comment: sampling it at 2x the highest frequency; though i think just over sampling it would be best (so just say 20000hz instead of 2c highest of (unknown) frequency)..    But anyways what your saying is to download sample it first.

Comment: It's usually better to just decide *a priori* what the highest frequency you need to handle is.  For audio, you might choose 20 kHz, since that's around the top end of what people can hear.  Then design your system around that: for 20 kHz, you might sample at 48 kHz, so your sampling filter has 4kHz between passband and stopband, making it easier to design.

Comment: Yea thats what i was saying, just to over sample it since the highest frequency is unknown in this situation. How should i go about making the sampling filter then in C? So it would be like this ADC -> downsample -> Re-resample using the new sampling filter -> DAC ( reconstruction). And i suppose only to use the board for the ADC processes

Comment: I was talking about the (analog) sampling filter before the ADC.

Comment: oh, ok. just to make to put it in a flow chart, what would the process be for the whole process of downsampling to resampling to reconstruction?

Comment: there's many ways to do it, but I would suggest ADC and DAC at 48kHz.  So the flow is analog signal -> sampling analog filter -> ADC -> resample down -> resample up -> DAC -> reconstruction analog filter.  If you sample with an audio codec it might include the reconstruction filter on the chip.  "resample down" and "resample up" will use a low-pass filter.  In fact this will be the *same* filter.   So if you don't need the downsampled stream for anything else, you could replace "resample down-> resample up" with "low pass filter" and have the same output.

Comment: So i guess the tricky part will be making the sampling analog filters and the low pass filter(Down and up sampling). Would you suggest doing this in several steps rather then one large code.

Comment: @Martin, audio > anti-aliasing > ADC > FFT > digital LPF > decimation > DAC > LPF

Comment: If you use an audio codec, just follow the datasheet and you'll have the analog part covered.  If you use a devboard, make sure it is designed to process audio (it will have an input and output jack) and the board will have the analog stuff covered for you.  The low pass filter is to go from the full sampled bandwidth (24 kHz, if sampled @ 48 kHz) to whatever bandwidth is "necessary" for your signal.  There are good web resources to design a digital low pass filter.

Comment: yea the dev board i have right now has all the required hardware for actual audio dsp processes i have the link im the main post to my board if you would i like to see it, and gives example DAC and ADC code for the microcontroller. So the main problem is the analog filter if i can find the digital low pass filter online.

Comment: Don't worry about the analog filter.  Your dev board will have it built in.

Comment: i found this fft filer online http://pastebin.com/39zN9phE , is that heading in the right track

Comment: No, that's not helpful.  Frankly, I'm puzzled at the purpose of your project, since a successful result will mean the output is the same as the input.  But the same is also true of a piece of wire.

Comment: Its just to show the effect of nyquist rate sampling, over and undersampling using a microconroller, but its turning out to be far more complicated then i had anticipated.

Comment: I suggest you do your DSP experimentation on your desktop with Octave or Matlab.  And start with "blink the LED" on the microcontroller.  Get good at both "DSP" and "microcontroller" before you attempt "DSP on microcontroller".

Comment: How hard would dsp on the computer be, forgetting the board entirely. The whole goal of my project is to study the effects of Nyquist, over-under sampling, and reconstruction of a audio track.

Comment: DSP on the computer is relatively easy.  Octave will have functions for loading an audio file and playing it back, and any kind of manipulation you can think of.  You will be free to concentrate on the math.

Comment: So it will have the dsp functions for over and undersampling? Is there any specific dsp libraries for octave or is it all there?

Comment: octave-forge has the user contributed libraries. There are probably functions to do the sampling, but if you are trying to learn, you should write your own.

Comment: Hey, mark you have been a lot of help, but this is all the time i have for now. Is there any way i can contact you with further questions?

Comment: @Martin, you should upvote his answer!

Comment: Just registered

Comment: Just post questions on here, you'll get lots of help.  In the meantime, poke around dspguru.com and read about sample rate conversion. http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/resampling

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the family guide and the Data sheet - [found here](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/msp430f5438.html) It will tell you how to setup the ADC and give some basic examples, also TI has sample code for the MSP430 line of chips which includes ADC10 and ADC12 examples.

Comment: I couldnt find the example code form the ones that ti gives you.

Comment: try finding your chip here http://focus.ti.com/mcu/docs/mcuprodcodeexamples.tsp?sectionId=96&tabId=1468

Comment: Ive tried looking though the example but have not found anything useful :(

Comment: you will not find any out of the box code that will work for your project, but it should give you a good place to start coding. Try using msp430x54xA_adc12_05.c (ADC12, Using an External Reference) and msp430x54xA_adc12_07.c (ADC12, Repeated Single Channel Conversions) from slac375a.zip.

Comment: ok will look, and someone suggested this nyquist sampling code. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/help-how-would-i-sample-an-audio-tract-at-nyquist-frequency-using-c-c-and-a-mi your thoughts? look at answer 2.

Comment: That sampling code is a good start.  If you have specific code questions about your board, you may also want to check out www.43oh.com, there forums have a lot of msp430 related code and projects.

Comment: Yea i was linked to that site before, jsolarski is there anyway i can get in contact with you via e-mail you seem like you know a lot about this, would be great for future question i may have.

Comment: Absolutely, Use the contact form on my website http://justinstech.org/contact-me/ I will respond with my email address in the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You will find things much easier if you use a proper DSP, I'd use a dsPIC. Microchip has FFT libraries.

Comment: How much do the dsPIC's run for? Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on the chip, it could be <$2. See the Microchip web site.

Comment: What would i need in the way of an experimenters board so i can have a hook up to my computer?

Comment: I'd design a small PCB.

Comment: It would be great if you can give me a suggested link to a board that would be good for my project. i also hear you can simulate data in matlab eliminating the need for a board.

Comment: You could use one of the Microchip boards. See the web site.

Comment: any recommendations though of which ones?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You should be able to find something suitable for yourself.

Comment: ill go take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [DSC Starter Kit](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en534506). It provides you with all of the software and hardware needed to get started with audio recording on a microcontroller. It also has some example programs.

DFT is a little bit more difficult, but there are prebuilt libraries for it. The problem is finding a free one and making sure you have enough ram to do all of the computations needed.

Comment: its not so much audio recording, my current board as a pre build recoding software, its sampling the data that im having trouble with.

Comment: @martin I am not sure what part you are needing help with. The board I linked to had code given to sample. If you want to know how to do an A-D conversion just read what the command is in the datasheet.

Comment: yea i saw it now after reading the examples more thoroughly, but i mainly need help with the sampling process using nyquist theorem in C.

Comment: What I would do is sample as fast as the hardware allows. I would then look for the highest frequency above a certain threshold. Double that and then use that for my sampling frequency.

Comment: Thats what i think ill end up doing. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/help-how-would-i-sample-an-audio-tract-at-nyquist-frequency-using-c-c-and-a-mi that one answer of how to sample in nyquist frequency.

Comment: @Martin I was pretty sure that method doesn't work. I went ahead and checked with a friend of mine and confirmed that it doesn't work. You are trying to avoid aliasing and there is no way for a microcontroller to know if you have aliased or not. You always have to start by oversampling and watching it for a bit. Then you can make an assumption of what the bandwidth of your input is and sample based on that.

Answer (score 0):

A program can only identify frequencies at half its sampling rate. There are two ways to deal with this:

1. **oversampling**: sample at more than twice the maximum possible frequency (eg. 48kHz > 2x20kHz), then compress the data by low-passing it (decimation) at the highest computed frequency.
2. **undersampling**: sample at some minimum frequency, then decide to sample at a higher frequency based on the power level in your highest computed frequency bin (FFT term). If it is above a certain threshold, increase the ADC sampling frequency.

The only way to succeed in *real-time* is with *oversampling*, as *undersampling* will have to either skip resampling the parts it has already sampled at too-low a frequency or request it to be replayed.

The [linked dev board](http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/msp-exp430f5438.html) seems expensive for this application. Is there more to your project? It has code examples of audio sampling and processing: [SLAC227](http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/slac227) (look in FFT.c).

Comment: Im planing on doing oversampling are my main experiment, then show the effects of undersampling on a 3 tone audio track. The reason i went with that board was 1) It was suggested 2) i can use it for multiple applications in the future.